# Dot products in spherical polars?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, coordinate-systems, geometry

In the book classical mechanics, it said that since the three unit vectors $\hat r$, $\hat \theta$ and $\hat \phi$ are mutually prependicular, we can evaluate dot products in spherical polars in just the same way as in Cartesians.
If
$$a=a_r\hat r+a_\theta \hat \theta + a_\phi \hat \phi$$
and  $$b=b_r\hat r+b_\theta \hat \theta + b_\phi \hat \phi,$$
then
$$a\cdot b=a_rb_r+a_\theta b_\theta+a_\phi b_\phi$$
I can't understand why the mutually perpendicular can deduce it?

Comment: you can write every vector with co-variant basis vectors or contra-variant basis vectors .with:

$\quad\,{a}=a_i\,\vec{g}^{i}\quad,$
${b}=b^j\,\vec{g}_{j}\quad,$

$a\,b=a_i\,\vec{g}^i\,b^j\,\vec{g}_{j}=a_i\,b^j\,\delta_j^i=a_i\,b^i$

where:$\quad\vec{g}_i\,\vec{g}_j\quad$ is the metric and $\quad\vec{g}^i\,\vec{g}^j\quad$ is the inverse metric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scalar product is bilinear. It means that if you take a vector $\overrightarrow{a} = A_1 \overrightarrow{a_1} + A_2 \overrightarrow{a_2}$ and $\overrightarrow{b} = B_1 \overrightarrow{b_1} + B_2 \overrightarrow{b_2}$, the scalar product will write:
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{a} \cdot \overrightarrow{b} &= (A_1 \overrightarrow{a_1} + A_2 \overrightarrow{a_2}) \cdot (B_1 \overrightarrow{b_1} + B_2 \overrightarrow{b_2}) \\
&= A_1 B_1  \overrightarrow{a_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{b_1} +  A_1 B_2  \overrightarrow{a_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{b_2} + A_2 B_1  \overrightarrow{a_2} \cdot \overrightarrow{b_1} + A_2 B_2  \overrightarrow{a_2} \cdot \overrightarrow{b_2}.
\end{align}

Now what happens in your case is that $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ are decomposed over the same orthonormal basis (vectors have a unit length and are "mutually perpendicular"). Two vectors being "perpendicular" means nothing more than the fact that their dot product is $0$. So if you develop your expression to let appear all the terms just as I did in my example, you will find the usual $a_r b_r + a_{\theta} b_{\theta} + a_{\phi} b_{\phi}$ (just like in Cartesian coordinates), plus all the terms proportional to $\overrightarrow{e_r} \cdot \overrightarrow{e_{\theta}}$,  $\overrightarrow{e_r} \cdot \overrightarrow{e_{\phi}}$ and $\overrightarrow{e_{\theta}} \cdot \overrightarrow{e_{\phi}}$, that will be equal to $0$ because $\overrightarrow{e_r}, ~ \overrightarrow{e_{\theta}}$ and $\overrightarrow{e_{\phi}}$ are mutually perpendicular.

Answer (score 3):

The result stems from the fact that the spherical coordinates are [orthogonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) (i.e., mutually perpendicular), which makes the unit vectors [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality), so we should have that
$$\mathrm{e}_i\cdot\mathrm{e}_j=\begin{cases}1&\text{for }i=j \\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
where $\mathrm e_i$ is the [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).

Another way of seeing this is through another common definition of the dot product as the magnitude of the two vectors times the angle between them:
$$a\cdot b=\Vert a\Vert \,\Vert b\Vert \cos\delta
$$
Perpendicular (orthogonal) axes have $\delta=90^\circ$ while aligned axes have $\delta=0^\circ$, which means that,
$$
\mathrm{e}_i\cdot\mathrm{e}_j=\begin{cases}\cos0^\circ\equiv1&\text{for }i=j \\ \cos90^\circ\equiv0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
which is the same as (1) above.